Pandas searching for string in column? Seems easy but I'm not getting any results
I have a pandas dataframe and one of the columns 'sigResponseActions' has the following data in it
 [{'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.collectInvestigationPackageResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.runAntivirusScanResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId,sha1'}]

How do I search for all rows in the dataframe that have 'stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction' or 'softDeleteResponseAction' ??
This gives no results...
strings = ['stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction', 'softDeleteResponseAction']
filtered_df = df[df['SigResponseActions'].isin(strings)]
filtered_df

This gives no results...
df1 = df[df['SigResponseActions'].str.contains('stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction',na=False)]
df1.head(5)

I'd appreciate any help...and REALLY appreciate any explanation WHY this doesn't work.
Thank you!

Please be explicit, provide a [mre] of your data. For instance what is the output of df['SigResponseActions'].head().to_dict()?

It doesn't look like you have strings, do you have dictionaries?

Ohhh, these are...ugh removing

Assuming this input with a column of dictionaries:
df = pd.DataFrame({'SigResponseActions':  [{'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.collectInvestigationPackageResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.runAntivirusScanResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId,sha1'}]})

You need to loop over the values in the dictionaries and the target strings:
strings = ['stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction', 'softDeleteResponseAction']

out = df.loc[[any(s in v for v in d.values() for s in strings) for d in df['SigResponseActions']]]

Output:
                                                                                                SigResponseActions
2  {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.security.stopAndQuarantineFileResponseAction', 'identifier': 'deviceId,sha1'}


try this:
mask = df.astype('str')['SigResponseActions'].str.contains('|'.join(strings), regex=True)
filtered_df = df.loc[mask]
print(filtered_df)

